# What is this plant with yellow large fruit?

Tags: species-identification, botany, trees

Found this in a garden in San Francisco. Can't decide if it's pomelo, capri lemon or something else, ideas?

[image]

Comment: How large are the fruit? It is definitely citrus.

Comment: Also, is it fruiting now?  (Mid April.)  It looks rather like a quince, but that fruits in the fall.

Comment: @jamesqf - quince have the opposite shape - pear-like; larger at bottom than top, rather than larger at top, smaller at bottom like these ones. Quince also have obtuse, thin paler green leaves, not glossy dark green ovate leaves. Also note spines on stems - definitely citrus.

Comment: @bob1: You're welcome to come look at my quince tree next fall :-)  And I don't see any spines on the stems.

Comment: @jamesqf - I am well aware of the shape of quince. Check out the ~horizontal branch just below middle of the pic. Look where the stalk of the leaf joins the branch. Also see the branch passing in front of wall on lower right of pic; see the spikes sticking out...

Comment: @bob1: There are a number of varieties of quince.  This is the variety I have: https://onegreenworld.com/product/aromatnaya-2/  As you can see, the fruit is not noticably pear-shaped, and the leaves are dark green and glossy.

Comment: @jamesqf: {Doyenne du comice] (https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Pyrus_communis_%27Doyenn%C3%A9_du_Comice%27.jpg) pear is similar. Turn the quince leaves over and they will be paler and slightly fuzzy, also on a reddish/brown stalk and brown bark cf. green stalks and green young (1-2 year) branches on citrus. Still note the fruit in the picture is smaller at bottom than top - opposite of quince. Actually most of the fruit in the pic are squashed spheres. All of them lack the bracts you see on the bottom of quince